# Readlines() and calculations in for loop

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a very long txt file with basically this structure:

```
   -97990.580   316472.190   452.080
   -97990.580   316472.190   452.070
   -97990.570   316472.190   452.060
   -97990.600   316472.190   452.040
```

So three blank at the beginning and three blank in between as separator.

I want to subtract a constant value (-316400,00) from column 2. I made a for loop that reads each line and strips each value in a single variable. Looks like this atm:

```
lineno=0            #Count lines
output_text = ""    #string variable holding all text to be written to   output file

for filen in change:
    lineno += 1
    finput = file(filen, "r")
    data = finput.readlines()
    linesplit = [elem.strip().split('   ') for elem in data]
    x = linesplit[0]
    print x
    y = linesplit[1] #-316400,00
   print y
   z = linesplit[2]
   print z
   output_text += "%s   %s   %s\n" % (x, y, z)   
   fileout.write(output_text)
   finput.close()
fileout.close()
```

Now the output file looks like this:

```
['-97990.580', '316472.190', '452.080']   ['-97990.580', '316472.190', '452.070']   ['-97990.570', '316472.190', '452.060']
```

It reads every row in the original text file as an element of a single list (if I print lineno it's 1). Also this way of course the subtraction for the y variable does not work. I used this strange looking linestrip variable as linesplit = data.strip().split("   ") but does not work for lists ('list' object has no attribute 'readlines')

Any help here? The output should basically look like this:

```
  -97990.580   472.190   452.080
  -97990.580   472.190   452.070
  -97990.570   472.190   452.060
  -97990.600   472.190   452.040
```

Comment: `316472.190 - 316400.00` produces `72.190`, not `472.190`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You produced a list of lists:

```
linesplit = [elem.strip().split('   ') for elem in data]
```

Here, each element in `linesplit` is a list too, one for each line. You then proceed to handle those lines as if they were *one* line. So `x` is assigned the first line from your file, `y` the second, and `z` the third.

Rather than read all data in one go, process your lines one by one by looping over the file object:

```
with open(filen, "r") as fileinput:
    for line in fileinput:
        x, y, z = line.split()
        y = float(y) - 316400
        output_text = "{}   {:.3f}   {}\n".format(x, y, z)   
        fileout.write(output_text)
```

The `with` line uses the file object as a context manager; files close themselves automatically when the context is exited (when the `with` block ends).

The line can be split with `line.split()`; it'll remove leading and trailing whitespace and split on *arbitrary width* spaces, be they 3 or otherwise. I then use tuple assignment to put the resulting 3 values into the variables `x`, `y` and `z`. I inserted a subtraction of 316400 for you as well by converting `y` to a float and subtracting. This does mean you need to be careful with formatting that back to a string; my code formats the numbers back to 3 decimals.

Quick demo of the output produced:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sample = '''\
...    -97990.580   316472.190   452.080
...    -97990.580   316472.190   452.070
...    -97990.570   316472.190   452.060
...    -97990.600   316472.190   452.040
... '''.splitlines(True)
>>> for line in sample:
...     x, y, z = line.split()
...     y = float(y) - 316400
...     output_text = "{}   {:.3f}   {}\n".format(x, y, z) 
...     sys.stdout.write(output_text)
... 
-97990.580   72.190   452.080
-97990.580   72.190   452.070
-97990.570   72.190   452.060
-97990.600   72.190   452.040
```

Comment: `with file(filen, "r")` shouldn't that be `with open(filen, "r")`? I guess using `file` also works, but isn't `open` "better", more "standard" etc?

Comment: @tobias_k: yes, I copied that from the OP. In Python 2, `file` is essentially an alias for `open()` (or `open()` returns an object of type `file` and uses the same signature). But `open()` is preferred, so I changed that now.

Answer (score -1):

Just Optionaly from me..
First, you can isolate each of the data.

```
a = ['-97990.580', '316472.190', '452.070']
>>> print a[0], a[1], a[2]
-97990.580 316472.190 452.070
>>>
```

Comment: That's what the OP did with `x = linesplit[0]`. You didn't address *why that doesn't work* however nor do you offer any solution.